# Error with wrap widget (suggestion) in Flutter after updating Android Studio and Flutter to 2022.2.1 Patch 1

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1 don't show wrap widget flutter

I am working in android studio (flutter) after the update Android Studio and Flutter to the last version. it became doesn't work suggestion (wrap with when right-clicking in a mouse). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc8PT.png)